# React process.env can't read environment variables in docker-compose.yml

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment

My React project use environment variables and there the variables in docker-compose.yml.
but they couldn't be read from the project.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: .
      target: app
    environment:
      - API_PROTOCOL=http
      - API_HOST=localhost
      - API_PORT=10000
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/share
    command: cp -R ./build /share
...
/* Ngnix Setting */
...
volumes:
  app-volume:
```

**api.js**

```
export const API_PROTOCOL = process.env.API_PROTOCOL || 'http';
export const API_HOST = process.env.API_HOST || 'localhost';
export const API_PORT = process.env.API_PORT || '8080';
export const getAPIUrl = () => {
  return `${API_PROTOCOL}://${API_HOST}:${API_PORT}`
};
```

And I printed using `console.log(getAPIUrl());`.

but it shows up default values like below.

**Output**

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

Comment: Thank you :) I put REACT_APP to prefix of environments but It didn't work still so I used env_file. and it works.